# ontextchanged event not working wihout pressing enter or tabbed in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, web, webforms

My code working properly but when I press enter or tab that time on `TextChanged` event fire and my code execute.
I want to search record without pressing enter or tab.

**ASP:**

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtNameSearch" runat="server" Width="300px" 
                ontextchanged="txtNameSearch_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void txtNameSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(txtNameSearch.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from customer_entry where name LIKE'" + txtNameSearch.Text + "%'",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        datagrid.DataSource = dt;
        datagrid.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: Oh look, a sql injection vector. Look up parameterised queries. Now.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Script properties

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myBox" MaxLength="14" runat="server" CssClass="textfield"
                                                    onkeypress="return Searchdata();" onkeyup="Searchdata();"
                                                    TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
```

Inside setphonenumberdata method call dopostback

```
 __doPostBack('Search');
```

and you can query database in server side

```
  string strText = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
                    if (strText.Equals("Search"))
                    {

                     // do code
                    }
```